# Why we should avoid as in dart

Tags: dart, compilation, runtime, lint

From dart lint rules I don't understand  why should we [avoid `as`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_as.html)

> **If you know the type is correct, use an assertion or assign to a more
>   narrowly-typed variable (this avoids the type check in release mode;
>   as is not compiled out in release mode)**. If you don't know whether the
>   type is correct, check using is (this avoids the exception that `as`
>   raises).

What are the implications at runtime if use:

```
(pm as Person).firstName = 'Seth';
```

instead of:

```
Person person = pm;
person.firstName = 'Seth';
```

---

Why is this good to have:

> this avoids the type check in release mode; as is not compiled out in release mode

Just performance improvement or will it avoid a crash if the type is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no difference in the Dart semantics between the two approaches, if the code is valid at all.

If `pm` has a type which is a supertype of `Person`, then the assignment gets an implicit `as Person` cast appended. This is the so-called "implicit down-cast" that Dart currently adds to some otherwise unsafe. If it has a type which is a subtype of `Person`, then it's assignable without a cast, and no cast will be added. If it's neither, then it's not assignable at all, and the code is a compile-time error.

Some compilers to JavaScript *may omit some of the checks* in their "production mode". That's not following Dart semantics, it's a kind of "unsafe optimization", and that's what the lint text is alluding to.
If your code runs natively, not on JavaScript, that does not apply and the lint text is misleading.
The production mode compiler could easily omit `as` casts as well. According to the text it currently doesn't (or didn't at the time the text was written).

That is entirely a *performance* optimization. It omits a cast because it *assumes* that it would have succeeded. That will "avoid the crash" if the type is wrong, but the code will likely crash soon after when the following code assumes that the type was actually right. It's not a way to avoid crashing, it's a way to lower the overhead of code which wouldn't have crashed anyway.

That's the *current* version of Dart. The Dart team is actively working on introducing sound non-nullable types, and one part of that is to remove implicit downcasts entirely. When that happens, the code `Person person = pm;` becomes invalid. You will have to write `Person person = pm as Person;` explicitly (no *implicit* downcasts), or more likely you'll just be writing `var person = pm as Person;`.

You should still only us `as` when you *know* that it will succeed. You can know that for any number of reasons, maybe because some class invariants ensure that a property has a particular type when another property has a specific value. If you do that, then unsafely optimizing production mode compilers will still generate functioning code.

If you don't *know*, you should test first. An `if (pm is Person) { .. pm is Person here .. }` test allows you to use a `pm` *local* variable at the type it was tested as, at least if the compiler can determine for certain that its value doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explanation! <3

Comment: this is pure gold